# Error in converting XML containing attribute values to Java Object

Tags: java, jaxb

I need to Unmarshal XML to Java Object, I have tried with below code but it is giving exception-

Main Class-

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(SimpleBean.class);
             Unmarshaller unMarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
             File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:config/SimpleBean.xml");
             SimpleBean param = (SimpleBean) unMarshaller.unmarshal(new FileInputStream(file));
             LOGGER.info("param: "+param.getRoot());
```

SimpleBean.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class SimpleBean {    

    @JsonProperty("root")
    private Root root;

    public Root getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(Root root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

}
```

Root.java

```
public class Root {
    @JsonProperty("Schedule")
    private List<Schedule> schedule;

    public List<Schedule> getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }

    public void setSchedule(List<Schedule> schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
    }
}
```

Schedule.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Schedule {
    @JsonProperty("ID")
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

SimpleBean.xml

```
<root>
<Schedule ID="561"></Schedule>
<Schedule ID="562"></Schedule>
</root>
```

Exception coming-

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"",
>   local:"root"). Expected elements are (none)

Comment: Are you sure that xml and something like `JsonProperty` actually work together? Shouldn't you be using `XmlElement` or `XmlRootElement`?

Comment: @f1sh- If I remove those JsonProperty annotations then I get null on this logging line- `LOGGER.info("param: "+param.getRoot());`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working solution-

SomeRoot.java-

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class SomeRoot{
    private List<Schedule> schedule;

    @XmlElement(name = "Schedule")
    public List<Schedule> getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }

    public void setSchedule(List<Schedule> schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
    }
}
```

Schedule.java -

```
public class Schedule {
    private String id;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "ID")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And then in java code-

```
         JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeRoot.class);
         Unmarshaller unMarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
         File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:config/SomeRoot.xml");
         SomeRoot param = (SomeRoot) unMarshaller.unmarshal(file);
         List<Schedule> schedules = param.getSchedule(); 
         for (Schedule schedule : schedules) { 
           LOGGER.info("Schedule: "+schedule.getId()); 
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an **@XmlRootElement** like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class Root {
    @JsonProperty("Schedule")
    private List<Schedule> schedule;

    public List<Schedule> getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }

    public void setSchedule(List<Schedule> schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
    }
}
```

Also, you don't need another wrapper POJO (SimpleBean).
You should do this directly (otherwise you'll get ClassCastException):

```
Root param = (Root) unMarshaller.unmarshal(new FileInputStream(file));
LOGGER.info("param: "+param);
```